# How to add the username to the log filename?

Tags: log4j

I am using Log4j to log some information and I am trying to concatenate the current username to the log filename. This is what I am doing.

log4j.appender.file.File=${userId}_file.log

The filename being generated is _file.log. How to add the username or userId to the log filename?

Answer (score 0):

replace `${userId}` with `${user.name}`, as below

`log4j.appender.file.File=${user.name}_file.log`